# installing ping identity agent for nginx on RHEL 7 (x86_64)

Tags: nginx, rhel, pingaccess

i have nginx installed on my machine (nginx version: nginx/1.11.10).
when i try to installing the pingaccess agent, i receive this error:

```
  Error: Package: pingaccess-agent-nginx-1.1.1-1.el7.x86_64 (/pingaccess- 
     agent-nginx-1.1.1-1.el7.x86_64)
       Requires: nginx-plus >= 1.11
```

this is strange to me however, as the agent-nginx version corresponds exactly with my version of nginx.

I have tried upgrading my version to the latest nginx version, with no luck.any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The agent is only supported on NGINX Plus, not the open source version.